# Multipart Upload in AWS failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an 18GB .vhd file to S3.

I have done the following process :

```
aws s3api create-multipart-upload --bucket amcaebucket --key 'multipart/01'
```

where my-bucket is the name of my bucket.

I got the following response :

```
{
"Bucket": "amcaebucket",
"UploadId": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"Key": "multipart/01"
}
```

My next command :

```
aws s3api upload-part --bucket amcaebucket --key 'multipart/01' --part-number 1 --upload-id "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

I got the following error :

```
An error occurred (AllAccessDisabled) when calling the UploadPart operation: All access to this object has been disabled.
```

What do I do??

Comment: Did you not provide some content for the part, with `--body 'local_filename_of_the_file_containing_this_part'`?

Comment: No, I have'nt..But 18 GB file has been transferred to S3 without asking for multiart Upload API..

Comment: That isn't possible, unless you are using a tool that handles it transparently for you.